# Openerp restrict user with one session at a time

Tags: session, openerp-7

Hi I am customizing OpenERP.  I want to restrict user to login into application once at a time.  That means; I have a user called "Accountant".  I want only one session should be allowed to login with "Accountant" user name at a time.  Others can login with their own user names.

Like that application should allow only one session for each user at a time.

I have not seen any plugin for this.  Can I do this through customization?

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

This blog highlights how to do it. But I don't think there is a live implementation of this available as open source http://www.zbeanztech.com/blog/how-restrict-multiple-logins-user-openerp-0

We do plan to do it ourselves as well but haven't had a moment yet.