# How to enable multiple sessions in Odoo?

Tags: python, oauth, odoo, erp

I need to let my users login to Odoo from different browsers at the same time. Currently it logs out from an older session when a user logs in through a different browser. I have tried a lot and have come up with some situations and observation but probably not close to the solution. No question on Stackoverflow has helped my situation.

**Situation -**

I log in through chrome using my google creds. Then again I log in through Internet Explorer using my same google username creds. However now if I try to refresh on chrome, I get signed out of Odoo. But I am still logged in on IE. Now if I try logging in on chrome using the same creds again, and then refresh Odoo homepage on IE, I get logged out of IE. So basically, the most recent log in session is kept and the rest are discarded.

I need to change this configuration such that a user can use Odoo from different browsers, and also different devices using the same username creds at the same time.

**Observations-**

The session files (eg - werzkzeug_2a182hs9d0f.....g3d8 **.sess** ) are stored in `C:\Users\Kaushaya\AppData\Local\OpenERP S.A\Odoo\Sessions`. 
Example situation -

1. I log in on Chrome (user1) - Created one session file
2. I log in on IE (user1) - Created one session file
3. I refresh page on already logged in session on Chrome (user1) - No new session file created and logged out of Odoo
4. I refresh page on newly logged in session on IE (user1) - Created one session file.

**Note:** under `Settings>oAuth Providers` I have only one `Google OAuth2` provider. Also, my users are mainly using Google OAuth to login.

What should I do in order to be able to let a particular user in Odoo login from different browsers/devices at the **same time using the same google accoun**t? Do I have to change anything in the `__openerp__.py` or `auth_oauth.py` or `res_config.py` or `res_users.py`? Or is it something not required any code change?

I have been observing and trying to understand where to look but I've spent hours on this without any luck. I hope to get some help/suggestion from StackOverflow.

Thanks!

Comment: Did some research, but found the reverse question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300488/openerp-restrict-user-with-one-session-at-a-time, I am not sure why you actually can't do it... Here there is an answer saying to access the IP of the server + port : https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/help-1/question/connecting-multiple-pcs-to-one-openerp-server-and-database-36715, and here a blog about making OpenERP aka Odoo prevent more then one connection for a single unser : http://www.zbeanztech.com/blog/how-restrict-multiple-logins-user-openerp-0

Comment: @Richard, I don't know if you got me right. I need to enable multiple sessions PER user. That is, for example, one user, multiple browsers/devices, same google account.

Comment: Yes, that what I said, I found the inverse requirement... So I am not sure if you actually not already have this behavior... Look at the second links above, the answer is about having multiple session for a single user...